# validationEngine('validate') not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I have a simple form I want to know if the form is at a valid state or not.

This project is using [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)

I am using the same version 2.6.2

According to the docs it supports a function `validationEngine('validate')` which returns true or false depending on the state of the form.

I keep getting the error `TypeError: $(...).validationEngine is not a function`
But strangely enough the form is throwing validation errors as required.

I did check that validationEngine Plugin is loaded after jquery and before the js file from which I am triggering the call. The form selector is also correct.

**The form:**

```
  <form name="editProfileForm" method="post" action="#" class="epf" id="editDiaryForm" style="display:none;">

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleCancel(this,'addPlay');$('#editDiaryForm')[0].reset();;" class="pull-right action-link">Cancel</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitDiary('#editDiaryForm');" class="pull-right action-link">Save </a>
        <input class="form-control validate[required, ajax[ajaxDiaryCall]]" name="title" id="title" type="text"/>
        <textarea class="form-control validate[required]" name="playdiary" id="playdiary"></textarea>

        <input type="hidden" name="Edit" value="playdiary" />
      </form>
```

**Attaching Validation:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#editDiaryForm").validationEngine('attach'); 
        //This throws true
        console.log($('#editDiaryForm').validationEngine('validate')); 
    });
```

**The submit function**

```
  function submitDiary(formid)
    {
      $(formid).bind('submit' , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Gives me the expected value
        console.log('Submiting Form - '+ formid);
        //Throws me an error here if commited
        $(formid).validationEngine();
        submit = false;
        //Gets stuck here
        if(submit == false && $(formid).validationEngine('validate') == true)
        {
          submit=true;
          $.ajax({
            url: url+'diary/save',
            async: false,
            type: "post",
            data: $(formid).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              if(data==true)
              {
                $('#diaries').prepend(data);
              }
              else
              {
                custom_page_msg('Something Went Wrong. Please Login to your account again to complete the action.');
              }
              submit = false;
            }
          });
        }

      });

      $(formid).submit();
 }
```

Script Order

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js'); ?>/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/languages'); ?>/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js'); ?>/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js'); ?>/jquery.customSelect.min.js"></script> 

<script src="<?php echo base_url('js'); ?>/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js'); ?>/other-validation.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js'); ?>/dropzone.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js'); ?>/global.js"></script>
```

Any guidence in regards to this would be very helpful.

**Update**

Its solved the issue was elsewhere. I found a file which was loading its own version of JS. Just a simple `jQuery.noConflict();` at the start of the submitDiary function did the trick. If you run into something silimar that might be it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is that you are trying to call some function when jQuery is not ready, the best whey to have a sync. process just bind click event on your buttons, and on click just handle all your data.

Bellow I have simple example which is working.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#editDiaryForm").validationEngine('attach');
    console.log("Here is type of validationEngine: ", typeof $("#editDiaryForm").validationEngine);
  
  $('#test').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('form').validationEngine('validate');
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
   <form name="editProfileForm" method="post" action="#" class="epf" id="editDiaryForm">
        <a id="test" href="#" class="pull-right action-link">Save </a>
      </form>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.2/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.2/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.2/jquery.validationEngine.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Genocide_Hoax I edited post this should work so just change the whey you call your request

Comment: I have updated my submit function. Please take a look.

Comment: Nope this wont work, how I told your onclick="" will be propagated async. try to set some ID and then bind a click event with jQuery, like in my example and let me know what will happen

Comment: thts the issue, I can't do that as the forms are created in a loop each having an id associated with the loop counter. So, I need a way to create the entire operation with the help of objects. I see no reason y it shouldn't work. And besides I tried replacing the formid with an actual id manually, same issue.